# Query for delete

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I have a Employee table in database which have two column employee_card and ledger_month. An Employee can have relation with multiple ledger month. Now I want to keep employee with his highest ledger month and rest will be deleted.

```
Input:
   Employee_card      Ledger_Month

    1                111112
    1                111114
    2                111112
    2                111114


  Output :

   Employee_card      Ledger_Month

    1                111114
    2                111114
```

I tried with a query like this

```
delete from v2titas.EMPLOYEE_COPY_UPGRADED where card 
not in(select card,max(ledger_month) from v2titas.EMPLOYEE_COPY_UPGRADED  group by card)
or 
ledger_month not in (select card,max(ledger_month) from 
v2titas.EMPLOYEE_COPY_UPGRADED group by card)
```

but it showing an error like this "too many value". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   DELETE FROM v2titas.EMPLOYEE_COPY_UPGRADED et
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM v2titas.EMPLOYEE_COPY_UPGRADED  it
WHERE et.card = it.card
AND et.Ledger_Month < it.Ledger_Month    );
```

Comment: Sorry,Yes card is emplyee_id

Answer (score 0):

try below query..

delete from emp_test where ledger_month in (select ledger_month from emp_test e where (employee_card, ledger_month) not in
(select employee_card, max(ledger_month) from emp_test e1 where e.employee_card=e1.employee_card group by employee_card));

Thanks,
Bala